# sympy: trigonometric sum-product identities

Tags: sympy

I have an expression: `sin(x)+sin(y)`

There is a well-known trig identity to express this as the product of sin and cos.

Is there a way to get sympy to apply this identity?

`simplify` and `trigsimp` do nothing.

Comment: Interestingly, `trigsimp` seems to work in the other direction, that is, `trigsimp(2*sin( (x + y)/2 ) * cos ( (x - y)/2 ))` gives you `sin(x) + sin(y)`. Perhaps sympy is interpreting `sin(x) + sin(y)` as the "more simplified" form. Do you know of other means of performing trig manipulations in sympy?

Comment: `expand_trig(sin(x) + sin(y))` also seems to be doing nothing

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`trigsimp`, as Aristocrates points out, does the reverse, because `sin(x) + sin(y)` is simpler than `2*sin((x + y)/2)*cos((x - y)/2)`.

`trigsimp` internally uses an algorithm based on a paper by [Fu, et. al.](http://rfdz.ph-noe.ac.at/fileadmin/Mathematik_Uploads/ACDCA/DESTIME2006/DES_contribs/Fu/simplification.pdf), which does pattern matching on various trigonometric identities.  If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/simplify/fu.py), all the identities are written out in individual functions (the functions are named after the sections in Fu's paper).

Looking at the list of simplifications at the top of the file, the one you want is probably

```
TR9 - contract sums of sin-cos to products
```

Testing it out, it looks like it works

```
In [1]: from sympy.simplify.fu import TR9

In [2]: TR9(sin(x) + sin(y))
Out[2]:
     ⎛x   y⎞    ⎛x   y⎞
2⋅sin⎜─ + ─⎟⋅cos⎜─ - ─⎟
     ⎝2   2⎠    ⎝2   2⎠
```

We would eventually like to factor these out into more user-friendly functions, but for now, the `fu.py` file is pretty well documented, even if all the function names are not particularly memorable.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for.  I didn't know about fu.py and I suspect that's true of lots of sympy users.

Comment: There is also a higher-level interface from the `fu` function. You can provide a "measure" function, which lets you redefine what kinds of expressions are "simpler".

Answer (score 1):

There does not seem to be a single function defined. You need to use the individual Fu functions as @asmeurer said. What I can contribute is a pointer to the official documentation explaining this: https://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/simplify/fu.html