# Counting trig ops as measure() function to fu() in sympy

Tags: trigonometry, sympy

How do I count the number of trig operations in an expression?

I have an expression of the form `a*sin(x)+b*cos(x)` that I would like sympy to convert to `c*sin(x+phi)`.

@asmeurer made a comment in [an earlier question about simplifying trig expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25355617/sympy-trigonometric-sum-product-identities) that suggested the fu() algorithm can be tuned to minimize an arbitrary measure.

I suspect I can get my expression to reduce if I set measure to be the number of trig ops in the expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is a way to get the *set* of functions:

```
>>> from sympy.functions.elementary.trigonometric import TrigonometricFunction
>>> eq=a*sin(x)+b*cos(x)
>>> len(eq.atoms(TrigonometricFunction))
2
```

If you wanted the actual number of times that such functions occurred (counting the same function more than once) you might try a custom function like preorder_traversal from sympy.core.exprtools, registering each time a TrigonometricFunction was encountered.