# simplify higher order terms with sympy.simplify.fu.TR8 into sum of angles

Tags: python, sympy

I would like to have [cos(a)*cos(b)]**k to be expanded to A*cos(n*a +/- m*b) where m, n, and k are integers, similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31104644/python3-sympy-expand-products-of-trig-functions), but I have found that higher order terms are not being expanded by sympy.simplify.fu:

```
import sympy as sp

sp.init_printing()

wlo,wrf,wif = sp.symbols('omega_LO omega_RF omega_IF',real=True,positive=True)
t,Vrf,Vlo = sp.symbols('t V_RF V_LO',real=True)

vrf = Vrf*sp.cos(wrf*t)
vlo = Vlo*sp.cos(wlo*t)

# Taylor Series expansion of exp(x)-1
x = sp.Symbol('x')
ts = (sp.exp(x)-1).series(n=5)
ts = ts.subs(x,vrf*vlo)

expanded_ts = sp.fu(ts, measure=lambda x: -x.count_ops())

print expanded_ts.args[-21]
```

produces the following result

```
V_LO**4*V_RF**4*(-cos(2*omega_LO*t) + 1)**2/1536
```

which has a squared term rather than a sum of angles term. Any idea on how to force higher order terms into sum of angles?

Comment: This might be considered as a bug in TR8. You may be able to get what you want by applying other functions in the fu module.