# Trigonometric identities

Tags: python, math, trigonometry, sympy

I have an expression which has both sines and cosines and would like to write it using only sines (or cosines), possibly using the [power-reduction formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Power-reduction_formula).

I tried to use SymPy but I cannot make it to "rewrite" to the desired output:

```
angle = symbols('angle')
print (sin(angle)**2).rewrite(sin, cos) # (1 - cos(2*angle))/2
print ((1 - cos(2*angle))/2).rewrite(cos, sin) # sin(angle)**2
```

Is there any way to tell Sympy to rewrite such expression using only sines (or cosines)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The `sympy.simplify.fu` module](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/simplify/fu.py) defines a number of transformations based on trig identities:

```
TR0 - simplify expression
TR1 - sec-csc to cos-sin
TR2 - tan-cot to sin-cos ratio
TR2i - sin-cos ratio to tan
TR3 - angle canonicalization
TR4 - functions at special angles
TR5 - powers of sin to powers of cos
TR6 - powers of cos to powers of sin
TR7 - reduce cos power (increase angle)
TR8 - expand products of sin-cos to sums
TR9 - contract sums of sin-cos to products
TR10 - separate sin-cos arguments
TR10i - collect sin-cos arguments
TR11 - reduce double angles
TR12 - separate tan arguments
TR12i - collect tan arguments
TR13 - expand product of tan-cot
TRmorrie - prod(cos(x*2**i), (i, 0, k - 1)) -> sin(2**k*x)/(2**k*sin(x))
TR14 - factored powers of sin or cos to cos or sin power
TR15 - negative powers of sin to cot power
TR16 - negative powers of cos to tan power
TR22 - tan-cot powers to negative powers of sec-csc functions
TR111 - negative sin-cos-tan powers to csc-sec-cot
```

I learned of these functions from [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sympy/wTXXjQg9Zyk) and [this post by asmeurer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25395386/190597).

---

```
import sympy as sy
from sympy import sin, cos
FU = sy.FU

angle = sy.symbols('angle')
expr = sin(angle)**2

print(FU['TR8'](expr))
# -cos(2*angle)/2 + 1/2

print(FU['TR5'](expr))
# -cos(angle)**2 + 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the thorough answer, this is really awesome!

Comment: You can just `import sympy.simplify.fu as FU`.

Comment: Actually, I guess you can't. Python's importing mechanism works weird.

Comment: But you can `from sympy import FU`, which gives you a dictionary of the functions.