# Symbolic integration slow with SymPy

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I'm not a `SymPy` expert, but I've used it successfully in some of my lectures in the last years. However, sometimes it seems to be very slow with symbolic integration. Here's an example that `Mathematica` computes almost instantly while `SymPy` needs a long time (more than half a minute) for it on my machine.

```
from sympy import *
x = symbols("x")

def coeff (f, k, var = x):
    return integrate(f(var) * cos(k * var), (var, -pi, pi)) / pi

f = lambda x: (11*sin(x) + 6*sin(2*x) + 2*sin(3*x))/10

[coeff(f, k) for k in range(0, 5)]
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this the expected behavior? Is there some trick to speed this up?

`SymPy` version is 1.0, `Python` is 3.5.1 64-Bit (Anaconda) on Windows.

Comment: What does slow mean in this case?

Comment: What I wrote in my question.  More than half a minute in SymPy versus instant reply on Mathematica.  Is that not enough information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can help guide the integration by telling SymPy to [expand products of
sin-cos to sums](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38163888/190597) (see also [[1]](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sympy/wTXXjQg9Zyk),[[2]](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25395386/190597)) before doing the integration:

For example,

```
In [58]: fprod(f, 4)
Out[58]: (11*sin(x)/10 + 3*sin(2*x)/5 + sin(3*x)/5)*cos(4*x)

In [59]: FU['TR8'](fprod(f, 4))
Out[59]: -sin(x)/10 - 3*sin(2*x)/10 - 11*sin(3*x)/20 + 11*sin(5*x)/20 + 3*sin(6*x)/10 + sin(7*x)/10
```

The integration is simpler in this form.

---

Therefore you could use:

```
import sympy as sym
x = sym.symbols("x")


def f(x):
    return (11*sym.sin(x) + 6*sym.sin(2*x) + 2*sym.sin(3*x))/10

def fprod(f, k, var=x):
    return f(var) * sym.cos(k * var)

FU = sym.FU
def coeff (f, k, var=x):
    return sym.integrate(FU['TR8'](fprod(f, k)), (var, -sym.pi, sym.pi)) / sym.pi

[coeff(f, k) for k in range(0, 5)]
```

---

Here is a benchmark using `FU['TR8']`:

```
In [52]: %timeit [coeff(f, k) for k in range(0, 5)]
10 loops, best of 3: 78.8 ms per loop
```

Using the original code (without `FU['TR8']`):

```
In [54]: %timeit [coeff(f, k) for k in range(0, 5)]
1 loop, best of 3: 19.8 s per loop
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for.